# How to detect if user rejects transaction

Tags: ethers.js

How could I detect this error  when the metamask modal shows up and user clicks reject? I'm using ether.js and web3Modal.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not use a try catch? Then in the catch you can watch for the 4001 which is specifically used for user requests denied.